# Make a git deployment owned by www-data

Tags: git, apache, deployment, permissions, debian

My `post-receive` hook deploys to `/home/repo`, where my Apache virtual host is pointing.
I would like `/home/repo` to be owned by `www-data`.

Should I add `git` to `/etc/sudoers` and allow it to execute a custom script that make `chown -R www-data:www-data /home/repo` as `root` after each pushing ? `git` don't seem to be able to do it as himself. Seems pretty insecure though.

**Edit**:
`post-receive` is doing a `git checkout -f` and `chmod -R 750 /home/repo` under `git` user. I just leave `git` own `/home/repo` and added `www-data` (or any Apache user) to the `git` group so it can read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. Why do you care about user ownership? Setting up some flexible group permissions and adding Apache user to your `git` group should be more than enough, in general. Other than that, I would really recommend you to take a look at [Capistrano](http://www.capistranorb.com) for deployment.

Comment: User `git` belongs to group `www-data` and `www-data` belongs to group `git`. Still, permission problems. When I'm pushing an empty `index.html` file, it's being deployed right but Apache returns a `403 Forbidden` error when accessing via my browser. It seems like files are being pushed with a `chmod 700`, so the group cannot read it. That's why I want to change owner to `www-data` in the first place.

Comment: Yes, but you are pushing as owner and can adjust the group permissions from within you `post-receive` hook, can't you?

Comment: I am pushing as user `git`. Example: I locally did a `touch perm.html` which is (locally) `-rw-r--r--`, then `git add perm.html && git commit -m "Added perm.html" && git push origin master`. On the server, it appears `-rw-------`. I don't understand why. What do you suggest?

Comment: Ideally, I'd suggest [Capistrano](http://www.capistranorb.com/) or something similar. But for a quick'n'dirty solution you can just add `chmod -R 750 /home/repo` to your `post-receive` hook, which is being run by `git` user, who also happens to be the owner of the `/home/repo` folder, so he shouldn't have any problems adjusting the permissions. Let me know if I'm getting the right idea of your setup.

Comment: I forgot to restart Apache after adding `www-data` to the `git` group, that's why I was getting the `403 Forbidden`. It works well otherwise. Thank you!